Не реагирует на кнопки
После нажатия кнопки марка или без марки бот пишет выберите марку или без марки и так бесконечно,а нужно чтоб он спросил марку,если нужна и если не нужна чтоб он отправлял текст
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

userData = {}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Гость")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Курьер')

    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Выберите режим:", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    if message.text == 'Гость':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("На машине")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Пеший')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Выберите способ передвижения:", reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'Пеший':
        userData[chat_id] = {'Mode': 'Гость', 'Transport': 'Пеший'}
        send_summary(chat_id)

    elif message.text == 'На машине':
        userData[chat_id] = {'Mode': 'Гость', 'Transport': 'На машине'}
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Введите номер машины:", reply_markup=markup)

    elif 'На машине' in userData.get(chat_id, {}).get('Transport', ''):
        userData[chat_id]['LicensePlate'] = message.text
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Марка")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Без Марки")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Выберите марку или без марки:", reply_markup=markup)

    elif 'Марка' in message.text:
        userData[chat_id]['Brand'] = message.text
        send_summary(chat_id)

    elif 'Без Марки' in message.text:
        send_summary(chat_id)


def send_summary(chat_id):
    if userData.get(chat_id, {}).get('Mode', '') == 'Гость':
        summary = f"{userData[chat_id]['Mode']}\n{userData[chat_id]['Transport']}"

        if 'LicensePlate' in userData[chat_id]:
            summary += f"\nГосномер - {userData[chat_id]['LicensePlate']}"

        if 'Brand' in userData[chat_id] and 'На машине' in userData[chat_id]['Transport']:
            summary += f"\nМарка - {userData[chat_id]['Brand']}"

        bot.send_message(chat_id, summary)


bot.polling()


@Amgarak Другой вопрос, в данном случае мне надо устранить проблему.

У вас проблема в условии elif 'На машине' in userData.get(chat_id, {}).get('Transport', ''): оно всегда будет True так как в словаре будет запись {'Mode': 'Гость', 'Transport': 'На машине'}

И в вашем предыдущем вопросе я уже рекомендовал вам использовать bot.register_next_step_handler(), прислушайтесь к совету и станет намного проще.

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py
